# Upload image in contact form

Tags: magento2, image, forms

Can we add an option to attach files/images to form submission?
This is so that customers can attach photos of any faulty items.
Please help me

Comment: sure you can. show us what you tried

Comment: I didn't try anything yet. I'm new to Magento 2 that is the reason I'm posting this comment.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to manage this?

Comment: I'm sorry. we're not here to provide you features. maybe you should look for a freelancer or search for extensions.

Comment: I'm asking the code and procedure to do it.